# Parent Entity as Owner in unidirectional One To One Relationship Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

consider the following DB Model:

[image]

In the data model I have two tables that share the same primary key, the strong entity is Account and the weak entity is User (user drags the Account's PK). Keeping this in mind: Is it possible to make the Account entity as Owner entity in a UNIDIRECTIONAL relationship between Account and User? If possible, how would the mapping be, otherwise why is it not possible?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`:

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "account")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

User table:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    .....
}
```

Look at [*this*](https://memorynotfound.com/hibernate-one-one-unidirectional-shared-primary-key/) to get details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I ask is that if a UNIDIRECTIONAL relationship is possible in the scenario that I have raised, your solution raises a BIDIRECTIONAL relationship, which does not answer my question. If it is not possible to get what I propose please tell me.

Comment: I recognize your effort, but although this mapping seems to be fine, if I create a 2 instances one account and one user and I assign the user to the account and then try to persist the account, it will generate an integrity error, meaning that hibernate can not manage the relationship automatically. In order for it to work, it must be done manually, first the account entity must persist so that hibernate generates its id, and then assign this id to the user entity in order for it to work. Many Thanks!

Comment: I am inclined to the answer to the question is not if we think from the perspective of the database even though hibernate is abstracted from it.